# Changing the variable of integer to a non-integer value

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you in advance for your help

I'm trying to create a flowchart of breast cancer staging and as this is my first time trying to do this in Excel, I wanted to see if I can get any help in defining a variable as a non-integer. 
In my case, I'm trying to define "InSitu" as String
And once I input the variable of "A2" as DCIS or LCIS, I want the "Stage" to pop out with "0" because a breast biopsy that is DCIS or LCIS is stage 0 breast cancer.

In the same vein, I'm trying to assign "N1a" as its own value and I want VBA to read it as it is rather than having to change N1a to N1.1. I hope this makes sense.

Sincerely,
JL

```
Sub read()
Dim InSitu As String, G As String, T As String, N As String, M As String, ER As String, PR As String, HER2 As String, Onc As String, Stage As String
InSitu = Val(Range("A2")) 
G = Val(Range("B2"))
T = Val(Range("C2"))
N = Val(Range("D2"))
M = Val(Range("E2"))
ER = Val(Range("F2"))
PR = Val(Range("G2"))
HER2 = Val(Range("H2"))
Onc = Val(Range("I2"))

If (M >= 1) Then
    Stage = "IV"
ElseIf (M = 0) And G = 2 And ER = 1 And PR = 1 And HER2 = 0 Or 1 And N = 2.1 And T = 1.2 Then
    Stage = "IB"
ElseIf (M = 0) And G = 2 And ER = 1 And PR = 1 And HER2 = 0 Or 1 And N > 2.1 Then
    Stage = "IIIA"
ElseIf (M = 0) And InSitu = DCIS Then
    Stage = "0"
End If
Range("J2").Value = Stage

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module?

Comment: Not sure why you are declaring your variables as strings if they are numbers?

Comment: Should `DCIS` be `"DCIS"` ? (that's why I asked about option explicit)

Comment: You've already declared `InSitu` as a string at the top of your procedure.